# PsExec and invalid handles

Tags: batch-file, scripting, remote-access, psexec

I am trying to use a windows batch script that uses PsExec to execute commands on a remote machine. Periodically it has "invalid handle" and the script then fails.

The script has not altered or indeed either machine.

Does anybody know why this happens as sometimes the scripts runs without a hitch.

Alternatively does anybody know how to run a script on a machine as the local user for that machine with a more reliable technology.

**PS** Sometimes the first `PsExec` works and the others fail.

**EDIT**

The script is just on line (apart from setting the appropriate variables)

```
 PsExec %HOSTNAME% -I -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% CMD /C RMDIR /S /Q e:\SomeDir
```

This sometimes works but sometimes fails with "invalid handle"

Comment: Your script is the key here, assuming it is not a connectivity issue.  But without seeing the script an answer is impossible.  Maybe they downvoted because the question is lacking the script?

Comment: @foxidrive - The script is not really the key but added the line. The problem is that the failure is intermittent and the only remedy so far is just to reboot the machine. Then it works for a while but eventually fails for some reason. NB: Computer screen not locked

Comment: How is it that you **know** that the executable is not the issue?  What **is** the problem, in your mind?  FWIW `rmdi.exe` doesn't return any hits on google.

Comment: @foxidrive Typo on my part "rmdir" - Was copying it from one machine to another (with one not on the internet)

Comment: Not enough detail.  "works for a while but eventually fails..." what does that mean exactly?  Run in a loop?  Run manually?  Run from scheduler?  How is it run?  What permissions is it run with and how to those relate to the hosts it's accessing?  How many hosts?  Whats different about the one it stops on?  OR is it a directory on the same machine that it stops on or... or... or... so much missing detail.

Comment: @RobHuston - It runs via Jenkins usually from one machine to another (just the two machines). Also fails periodically when run from the command line. For example last night it was OK at 1am, failed at 2am, ok at 3am and 4am. Nothing happening on the network

Comment: Hello Ed. Please could I request that you keep a log of when the script fails. This could possibly be automated within the script by adding a command at the start of the script that appends the date/time the script was last run to a file, and another command at the end of the script that appends the date/time of the last success to a file. These dates can then be run through to catch dates/times of failures.

Comment: If my previous post fails to illuminate the problem alone then step 2 is to treat the script as a collection of bite-size successes - they can be thought of as checkpoints, and an entry added to the log each time the checkpoint is reached, but please try the simpler approach first. I really hope that this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to debug the situation.

You have a script, then something (what is Jenkins?) launch it on a remote PC, sometime it works, sometime it fail.

Is it deterministic?
When it fail does it always fail?
How does it fail?

**You need to acquire better knowledge of how/when the script fail.**

Here is what I would do to gather better understanding of these fails.

**Can you run the script multiple time?**
From the comments it seem that you run the script every hours, can you run it 3/4/5 time in a row, for each hours?
This will help you to determine how it fail: if you run it 5 time, does it works every time? it it fail, does it fail 5 times in a row?

**Can you try to use different script?**
You can create some more similar, but simpler, scripts.
So you can try your script with the RMDIR, then another script with a simple DIR command (just to se if the script launching/connection mechanism works) then another script with a simple ECHO command (so it doesent need to access any files/folder)

**Run debug scripts on the local PC**
Then, you can simultaneously run other scripts that run on the LOCAL PC (not the remote one where you need to execute the RMDIR) that try to access the remote PC, with a PING, or by copying a file from/to a network share...

**Sniff the network**
You can even set up a Wireshark instance that log all the packet sent between the 2 PC, this can be helpful to analyse/exclude networking issue.

**You clearly need to track/log everything.**

With this kind of information maybe you/we can have a better understanding of where the issue is.

=====================================

## **UPDATE 1 - Record some log**

=====================================

Maybe you can try to use the following modified scripts to have some log files.
These script will create 2 log files, one on the remote PC (containing the message of the remotely executed command) and one on the local PC (containing any message from PsExec)

*(you'll need to tweak the path where the log file are saved)*

```
psexec %HOSTNAME% -I -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% CMD /C "RMDIR /S /Q e:\SomeDir >>c:\RemoteComputer.log 2>&1" >>c:\LocalComputer.log 2>&1
```

or the following one without the /I
Are you sure you need the /I parameters for CMD? On my Pc it doesn't works if I use the /I parameters...

```
psexec %HOSTNAME% -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% CMD /C "RMDIR /S /Q e:\SomeDir >>c:\RemoteComputer.log 2>&1" >>c:\LocalComputer.log 2>&1
```

After some testing on my PCs, I've seen that PsExec install a service on the remote PC to run the command remotely. (It's called PsExecSvc.exe, installed in c:\windows\ on the WinXP PC I'm using for this test)
The remote installation/uninstallation of this temporary service for the command execution can surely be one of the possible "failure point" that generate the error.
If this is the case, then you should be able to track this down by looking at the  LocalComputer.log, that will contain the message/error from PsExec.

As stated in my previous advice, I would also try to schedule simpler script like

```
psexec %HOSTNAME% -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% CMD /C "dir c:\ >>c:\RemoteComputerDir.log 2>&1" >>c:\LocalComputerDir.log 2>&1
```

and

```
psexec %HOSTNAME% -u %USERNAME% -p %PASSWORD% CMD /C "echo SuperEchoTest >>c:\RemoteComputerEcho.log 2>&1" >>c:\LocalComputerEcho.log 2>&1
```

===================================

## **UPDATE 2 - Try to use WMI**

===================================

You can try to run the remote command by using WMI

```
wmic /node:%HOSTNAME% /user:%USERNAME% /password:%PASSWORD% process call create "CMD /C RMDIR /S /Q e:\SomeDir"
```

When you use WMI you need to be sure that windows firewall is not blocking your command.   (when I tried to run a remote command with WMIC the windows firewall notification popped up on my Win 7 PC)
(I've the instruction to use WMIC [here](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/05/episode-31-remote-command-execution.html))

Comment: 1. Jenkins is an auto build system. See http://jenkins-ci.org/. 2. I have created the simplest script I can think of. Just delete a directory that gets created by schedule on the 1/2 hour. 3. The script just runs the one command. `psexec` i.e. run it on the remote machine. 3. What is there to log- psexec outputs `invalid` if it does not work! 4. If you have a suggestion as to another technology to execute a command on another machine I would be grateful. Tried powershell but the cross domain bit is problematic.

Comment: @EdHeal I've just added some log-enhanced scripts to the answer

Comment: This [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2504.enable-powershell-remoting-with-client-outside-of-server-s-domain-trusted-host-and-double-hop-issue.aspx) may help you

Comment: @StathisAndronikos - Thanks for the link - will give it a go. if it works I will ask you to post a question to enable you to get the bounty

Comment: @EdHeal I just added another way to run the remote command by using WMI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more reliable technology for executing commands on a remote machine and is called [powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx). For example, you can run :

```
test-connection -computername server01, server02, server12
```

pings from  local computer to several remote computers.

Another very useful command is:

```
invoke-command -filepath c:\scripts\test.ps1 -computerName Server01
```

runs the Test.ps1 script on the Server01 computer.

A [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) gives several examples on how to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers.

Comment: Cross domain authentication is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

A different technology can be found mimicking the Linux world, and using **ssh**. It's very common with clusters and I have personally used it with Windows Server 2008 R2, so I don't expect any difference on windows 7.

This task is commonly performed with ssh and password-less public key authentication. With it, the only needed information is the IP of the remote server and the public key of the client, stored on the server: only the client with the corresponding private key can connect to it (the keys must be created with `ssh-keygen`, on the client. The public key is copied to the server)

The server must have the TCP port 22 accessible from outside, in case there are firewalls, NATs,...

In my case I used the ssh server included in [Windows SUA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771672.aspx), but I suggest you forget them (they are deprecated, and quite cumbersome actually) and give a try to the OpenSSH [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) server, sshd - even if not officially Microsoft, there is a large community supporting it at least - and occasionally I have used it reliably.

The client ssh command is included in SUA, in cygwin, or you can use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) if you want a lightweight solution on the client (not that cygwin is heavy - just the burden of having a sort of linux emulation that's not needed)

Giving a search for example I have found [this post](http://www.setgetweb.com/public/keyauth.html), explaining well the needed steps.